# How to write to Source Code from Custom Control Designer?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, custom-controls, designer

I am trying to create a user control that will modify some source code a template generates.

I have tried getting the Assembly location from the custom ControlDesign I have created, but this is the Visual Studio .exe location, not the source code location.

```
        Private Designer As BulkOpsVesselGridControlDesigner

        Public Sub New(ByVal Designer As BulkOpsVesselGridControlDesigner)
            MyBase.New(Designer.Component)
            Me.Designer = Designer
        End Sub

        Public Property GridType() As BulkOpsGrids
            Get
                Return Me.Designer.VesselGridControl.GridType
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As BulkOpsGrids)
                Me.Designer.VesselGridControl.GridType = value

                If value = BulkOpsGrids.NewGrid Then
                    'Display Input from Developer
                    Dim gridName = InputBox("Please Type out the name of the Grid Type Without Spaces. Ex: WorkingCrane")
                    'TODO: Get file path programmatically (based on developer)
                    Dim path = "C:\BulkOpsWinUILib\UserControls\GridPropertyData\BulkOpsGridData.vb"

                    Dim fileExists As Boolean = IO.File.Exists(path)
                    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(IO.File.Open(path, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                        'TODO: write logic for formatting and proper placedment
                        sw.WriteLine(gridName)
                    End Using
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
```

Ultimately, I would like if the developer selects the option "newGrid" I would like it to automatically prompt for details for the grid definition and then add the option to the proper source code.

The hope is to create a template that can be used to help standardize how we build these controls in future applications. The template itself will help create and build source code as needed. Similar to how to designer automatically writes to the .designer file.

[Image Of File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trrsA.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want to automate Visual Studio from within a control's designer code.  You can obtain a reference to the [DTE Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) by using the [IServiceProvider.GetService(Type) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider.getservice?view=netframework-4.8).  A component's [Site Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.site?view=netframework-4.8) implements the `IServiceProvider` interface.

Once you have the DTE reference, you can retrieve information about the currently loaded solution and do anything the VS Object model allows, including adding new items to a project.

The example below is loosely based on the question and shows how to obtain various path information as that appears to what you are asking about.  The smart-tag SomeProp property setter will set the custom Label's text property to display the obtained information.

```
' Project References:
'   • System.Design
'   • ENVDTE

Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design

<Designer(GetType(TestControlDesigner))>
Public Class TestControl : Inherits Label
  Public Sub New()
    AutoSize = True
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestControlDesigner : Inherits ControlDesigner
  Private _actionLists As DesignerActionListCollection

  Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ActionLists As DesignerActionListCollection
    Get
      If _actionLists Is Nothing Then
        _actionLists = New DesignerActionListCollection({New MyActions(Me.Component)})
      End If
      Return _actionLists
    End Get
  End Property

  Private Class MyActions : Inherits DesignerActionList
    Public Sub New(component As System.ComponentModel.IComponent)
      MyBase.New(component)
    End Sub

    Private _SomeProp As String
    Public Property SomeProp As String
      Get
        Return _SomeProp
      End Get
      Set(value As String)
        _SomeProp = value
        Dim serviceProvider As IServiceProvider = Me.Component.Site
        Dim dte As EnvDTE.DTE = CType(serviceProvider.GetService(GetType(EnvDTE.DTE)), EnvDTE.DTE)
        Dim doc As EnvDTE.Document = dte.ActiveDocument
        Dim proj As EnvDTE.Project = doc.ProjectItem.ContainingProject
        Dim cntrl As Control = CType(Me.Component, Control)
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(1000)
        sb.Append($"Document Path: {doc.Path} {Environment.NewLine}")
        sb.Append($"Document Fullname: {doc.FullName} {Environment.NewLine}")
        sb.Append($"Project Filename: {proj.Properties.Item("FileName").Value} {Environment.NewLine}")
        sb.Append($"Project File Path: {proj.Properties.Item("LocalPath").Value} {Environment.NewLine}")
        cntrl.Text = sb.ToString()
      End Set
    End Property
  End Class
End Class
```

Comment: This looks like just what I was looking for. I appreciate your reply and I hope to try this soon!

Thank you so much!